# EventBus: Registering without any @Subscribe annotated method

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I have a `BaseFragment` class which registers/unregisters itself to `EventBus` in `onStart()/onStop()`, and several child classes that inherit from it (`FragmentA`, `FragmentB`...). The base class doesn't have any methods annoted with `@Subscribe`, and `FragmentA` neither, but I want it to register anyway **in case** I add some in the future.

If I register an object that doesn't have any `@Subscribe` annotated method, I except nothing to happen, like when using [SquareUp's Otto](https://github.com/square/otto), but EventBus throws an exception :

```
org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.company.app.FragmentA and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation
```

Why throw an exception ? I mean, it doesn't prevent the app to run.

Is the only solution to wrap the `register()/unregister()` calls in `BaseFragment` into an ugly `try ... catch` or is there a cleaner workaround?

Comment: Your methods with @Subscribe annotation must be public, check all of them.

Comment: @oguzhand If you read closely, you can see that I have no methods with the `@Subscribe` annotation at all.

Comment: can you implement a dummy annotated method in base fragment?

Comment: why don't you add an empty `@Subscribe` method? i think its throwing exception just in case user forget to add the `@Subscribe` method.

Comment: @Anders Good idea! Thanks!

Comment: @Anders Can you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your child fragments to be able to have no `@Subscribe` method without any exception to be thrown, just put an empty subscriber in the base class :

```
@Subscribe
public void dummyEvent(SomeClassThatWillNeverBePosted event) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register/unregister seperately for each fragment. Because if you do this in base fragment your child fragments register same events but each fragment has different events.